Radix UI type error when trying to "react-accordion"
I am trying to import  react accordion root component and then export it back in my project while renaming it as Accordion but currently i receive type error Unsafe assignment of an `any` value
Not sure how to fix it as i already tried forcing types with as
import * as React from "react";
import * as AccordionPrimitive from "@radix-ui/react-accordion";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

const Accordion = AccordionPrimitive.Root;


PS- I don't want to disable this eslint rule

By defining the type of AccordionProps based on the props of AccordionPrimitive.Root, you ensure that the exported Accordion component has the correct type information.

import * as React from "react";
import * as AccordionPrimitive from "@radix-ui/react-accordion";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

type AccordionProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof AccordionPrimitive.Root>;

const Accordion: React.FC<AccordionProps> = AccordionPrimitive.Root;

export { Accordion };

